# I'm did POST method for DELETE with correct parameters and URL in React application but receive 400 Bad request error. Can it be server side issue?

Tags: rest, post, onclick, http-error, 400-bad-request

#API  #HTTPrequest #BadRequestError

I'm trying to do a HTTP POST method to delete a resource from the Database in a React js application. Parameters and URL are passed correctly along with the header containing the required parameters but receiving a 400 Bad Request error. Can it be caused by a server-side issue?